# Creating decorator inside class as method gives error with self

Tags: python, exception, functools

I am trying to create decorator inside class and need to access self inside the decorator

This is my code

```
import functools
class Rtest(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key1 = "foo"
        self.value1 = "bar"


    def continue_exception(self, func, **kwargs):
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def inner_function(*args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    import traceback
                    print(f"Error with {kwargs.get('key')} :  {kwargs.get('value')}")
                    print(f"Exception {traceback.format_exc()}")
                    return
            return inner_function

    def add1(self, n1, n2):
        return n1 + n2

    @continue_exception(key=self.key1, value=self.value1)
    def add2(self, n1, n2):
        return n1 + n2


obj = Rtest()

print(obj.add1(4,5))

print(obj.add2("fdfd", 6))
```

I get this error

```
@continue_exception(key="foo", value="bar")
```

TypeError: continue_exception() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'func'

Answer (score 0):

Your program has the following problems:

1. There is a problem with the definition of your decorator function. When it is used in `@continue_exception(key="foo", value="bar")`, there is no `func` parameter, it will only receive the positional parameters you pass in. Because at this time it is executed first, and then the decoration function is performed.
2. `continue_exception` is an instance method, you can't use it as a decorator unless you can pass an object to it. So you can make it a static method, yes, you can, because `self` is not used inside the function.

The following code fixes the above issue and runs successfully.

```py
import functools
class Rtest(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key1 = "foo"
        self.value1 = "bar"


    @staticmethod
    def continue_exception(**kwargs):
        def wrapper(func):
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def inner_function(*args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    import traceback
                    print(f"Error with {kwargs.get('key')} :  {kwargs.get('value')}")
                    print(f"Exception {traceback.format_exc()}")
                    return
            return inner_function
        return wrapper

    def add1(self, n1, n2):
        return n1 + n2

    @continue_exception(key="foo", value="bar")
    def add2(self, n1, n2):
        return n1 + n2


obj = Rtest()

print(obj.add1(4,5))

print(obj.add2("fdfd", 6))
```

Output:

```py
9
Error with None :  None
Exception Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wujun/Projects/code_test/test.py", line 15, in inner_function
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wujun/Projects/code_test/test.py", line 29, in add2
    return n1 + n2
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

None
```

---

If you want to get the values of `key1` and `value1` in real time, you can make the following modifications.

```py
import functools
class Rtest(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key1 = "foo"
        self.value1 = "bar"


    @staticmethod
    def continue_exception(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner_function(*args, **kwargs):
            self, *_ = args
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                import traceback
                print(f"Error with {self.key1} :  {self.value1}")
                print(f"Exception {traceback.format_exc()}")
                return
        return inner_function

    def add1(self, n1, n2):
        return n1 + n2

    @continue_exception
    def add2(self, n1, n2):
        return n1 + n2


obj = Rtest()

print(obj.add1(4,5))

print(obj.add2("fdfd", 6))
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to access key1  like this `key=self.key1`  as it will be dynamic and i cant hard code it like `key="foo"` unless i can access self inside function `Error with {self.key1}`

Comment: @Motaro Just like the decorator error mentioned above, you don't have `self` at this point, unless it is your class property or global variable.

Comment: You can get the class instance object through the `args` parameter in the function `inner_function(*args, **kwargs):`, and its first value is, like this `self, *_ = args`.

Comment: is it possible to pass key,value `continue_exception(func, **kwargs):` and then use like `@continue_exception(type="bar")`

Comment: i copied ur code as given and give this error `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable`

Comment: @Motaro You just need to combine the two examples and you can use it like this (`@continue_exception(type="bar")`).

Comment: @Motaro How do you use it, I have no problem running it locally.

Comment: https://trinket.io/python3/50a24dbbb1

Comment: @Motaro I don't know what's going on, it's fine locally. I moved the function `continue_exception` outside the class and it works, the effect is the same. https://trinket.io/python3/50a24dbbb1

Comment: @Motaro You can use Python 3.10!